# What would be natural way to say this?

Tags: phrase-request, expressions

Recently I was watching a movie with someone which had a good amount of grandiloquence, as is common in any historical love story where things always tend to be regal, which are really good to hear but takes some effort to understand fully on the part of listener. After the movie ends, the other person said that it's because the actors are 'getting paid' that they are able to romance in such a way on screen, nobody does that in real life. This irked me a bit and I wanted to tell him to not ruin the entire mood by maligning these passionate entities with materialistic motivations. He holds a pretty cynical (or just too practical?) world view that people do things for money. I want to precisely tell him to stop being such a "romance-less grouch" (I hope this combination of words makes sense).

What would be a natural way to say that? I want a phrase/sentence which would fit particularly capturing this incident. I could say that "*You need to be a romantic to understand this thing*" but this would be a belittling reply. A few other examples that I have thought of are :

> *1. Money is not everything.*
>
> *2. There are some things money can't buy.*

All these don't really capture that I am specifically pointing towards the blissfulness of tender moments in such movies beside being too cliched.

Comment: Nobody would ask for more context. You have given the entire context. Well written question.

Comment: So less number of times this post has been seen. :(

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could use a combination of two famous phrases. Might I suggest one:

> **"Money cannot buy everything. Some things in life are truly priceless."**

This not only conveys that *'money isn't everything'* but also that

> **"Not everything in life comes with a price tag'**.

Oh wait! That's also pretty catchy. But its up to you. There are an infinite number of things you can tell him to express your opinion. You can phrase your own sentences, use famous phrases or sentences, or even quotes by famous personalities.

Comment: I don't care too much for money, money can't buy me love! No, no, no, nooooo! - The Beatles